# Can't load custom template

Tags: custom-templates

We need to customise a template called 'Selector.tpl', we have identify this template with debugging on and copied it into `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates/` and this directory is declared in Directories. We followed the documentation and it should work fine when it doesn't. The template is not loaded. We've tried on the original file that gets modify in the desired way but we want to use the custom one. Folder has 755 rights on and File has 644 on. Is there something special to care about?

[image]

Comment: What is the actual path of Selector.tpl in your custom template file?

Comment: `/home/domain/testwpcivi/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates/Selector.tpl`. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selector.tpl is placed wrong hence its not invoked. It should follow exact path of CiviCRM core module

For example if the Selector.tpl in Core is placed under `plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Selector.tpl` than in template over-ride it should be `/home/domain/testwpcivi/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Selector.tpl`

Once you have tpl placed under correct directory path clear civicrm cache

Comment: this is it! I read this in a post from 2011 and I wasn't sure it still was the right way. thank.